# What is the transluscent background of a modal dialog called?

Tags: web-app, terminology, modal-windows

These days it's common for modal dialogs to also reduce the brightness of the background content, to make it clear that it can't be interacted with. This is especially common on the web.

**What is the name of the darkening behind the modal?**

[image: Example of a modal dialog]

Since I've never known the standard name, I have resorted to a slightly silly name: *sneezeguard*.

Comment: Ah, it [seems to be called an "overlay"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9268593/jquery-set-modal-dialog-overlay-color). That makes sense.

Comment: Can you clarify if you're looking for opinions on what a good semantic term would be for that element, or do you want to know how various UI frameworks actually refer to it?

Comment: @LukeSmith uh... both, either? I thought that there would be a clear, standard name. (I'm realising that there are at least a couple of contenders).

Comment: Ultimately, I want advice on what *I* should call it. I'd rather use an existing, accepted term, but it would be great if it was also descriptive.

Comment: Any particular reason you need to refer to it as anything besides what the framework has decided to call that particular DOM element? See the answer below re: Bootstrap's modal.

Comment: Just so I know what word to use in code and when talking with the team about it.

Comment: In that case Garik's answer is good in that it illustrates how it depends on the framework you're using. Bootstrap calls it one thing. Another framework may call it something else.  And if you code your own framework, feel free to call it sneeze guard.

Comment: You asked for a term for "the darkening behind the modal." The backdrop to the modal is everything behind the modal. A scrim is part of the backdrop. A scrim is also a part of a lightbox effect. Scrim describes that specific visual effect.

Answer (score 11):

It is refereed to as "modal **backdrop**"

in Bootstrap documentation at [Modal / Options](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#options)

Comment: w3schools isn't a good place to find sources.

Comment: You could change the link to the actual [Bootstrap documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#options).

Comment: The new(ish) HTML dialog element also calls is a backdrop, it has a pseudo-element for that: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dialog

Answer (score 6):

This is called a lightbox effect. It can also be referred to as 'out of focus,' as in, the modal is now in focus and the window behind it is disabled.

https://uxplanet.org/best-practices-for-modals-overlays-dialog-windows-c00c66cddd8c

Comment: In fact, that is not at all an "effect". It is a separate element (div) with a clear purpose, a HTML component with a group of CSS proprieties.

Comment: @insidesin Really? “Effect” Is the term you use for html elements? Please show a reference if you want to continue this conversation and limit the comments to the subject, not to my skills. Happy holidays to you too!

Comment: [effect](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/effect)
```something that is produced by an agency or cause; result; consequence:
Exposure to the sun had the effect of toughening his skin.
```

Comment: One word holds many meanings. A doughnut is edible, a doughnut can be made by a car. Neither of these cancel the other out, they are one word with multiple meanings.

Answer (score 4):

Google Material Design Guidelines call it Scrim: https://material.io/design/environment/surfaces.html#attributes

> Scrim
>
> Scrims are temporary treatments that can be applied to Material surfaces for the purpose of making content on a surface less prominent. They help direct user attention to other parts of the screen, away from the surface receiving a scrim.
>
> Scrims can be applied in a variety of ways, including:
>
> - Darkening or lightening the surface and its content
> - Reducing the opacity of the surface and its content
>
> Multiple surfaces on a screen at a time can display scrims. Scrims can appear at any elevation, whether in the foreground or background.

Comment: yes, Material took this name from theaters lightning and some old digital design lingo for printing. That's how I call it, but backdrop is used a lot as well

Answer (score 3):

The background behind the modal is blurred and darkened for a 3D effect to get more visual contrast and make the background recede visually.

A good word for the dark, transparent layer over the blurred background is scrim. Scrim is something used to physically cover the lights in photography and film shoots - to get lighting effects.

[Here's the word scrim being used in Material Design guidelines.](https://material.io/design/components/navigation-drawer.html#)

Users should be able to tap or click on the background cover, or scrim, to close whatever is opened in the foreground. Like they're tapping on the background to open it back up.

Answer (score 3):

In the last years, the term I always found in frameworks for the transparent background of a modal/ dialog/ pop-up is **overlay**.

See: [Considerations for Styling a Modal](https://css-tricks.com/considerations-styling-modal/).

> Dealing with the **overlay** A modal is often accompanied by a
>   full-screen-covering overlay. This is useful for a number of **reasons**:
>
> - It can darken (or otherwise mute) the rest of the screen, enforcing
>     the "you need to deal with this before you leave" purpose of a modal.
> - It can be used to prevent clicks/interactions on stuff outside the
>     modal.
> - It can be used as a giant close button. Or "cancel" or whatever
>     the most innocuous action is.

In material design is used the term **backdrop**.

[image]